# Can't discover the service following Walkthrough: Binding WPF Controls to a WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf-data-services

I'm following the [Walkthrough: Binding WPF Controls to a WCF Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

But when I try to Discover the service I get an error saying that there was an error downloading metadata from the address

[image]

What could it be?

**EDIT**:

It basically creates an ASP NET Web App, adds an ADO Nen Entity Model, Adds a WCF Data Service, adds a WPF App to the solution, and tries to add a new data source from the service, the Add Service Reference appears, and it's there where the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Simply added this to the ServiceModel configuration in App.config

```
  <services>
      <service name="AdventureWorksService"
               behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport">
          <endpoint
              address="http://localhost:12141/AdventureWorksService/mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"
          />
      </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="metadataSupport">
              <serviceMetadata/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Comment: I changed the localhost number but it did not work... tryed it in WEB.CONFIG and APP.CONFIG... I tryed even with adding <system.serviceModel>...</system.serviceModel>

Answer (score 0):

My system spec:

- Windows 7 x64
- MS SQL Server 2014
- VS 2015 Community Ed.
- .net Framework 4.6.2

I'm doing the same walkthrough and have passed this error by following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087982/Create-a-WCF-DataService-in-Visual-Studio?display=Print) (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087982/Create-a-WCF-DataService-in-Visual-Studio?display=Print)

*Changed parts in italics*

Do the change below in the 'Create the service' and 'Configure the service' part of the walkthrough.

The relevant parts from the CodeProject article are Step 11: Add the entity framework provider for OData via nugget command line.

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider -Pre

and Step 12: Edit the *AdventureWorksService*.svc file and:

- Add the using statement for System.Data.Services.Providers
- Change inheritance from DataService to EntityFrameworkDataService
- Change the  to be the name of your entity model in my case
  *AdventureWorks2014Entities*

Optionally:

- Set the access rules for your entity names. Use the star symbol to mean all entities.
- Set the UseVerboseErrors property in order to see proper feedback of
  errors.

> ```
> using System.Data.Services.Providers;
>
> namespace AdventureWorksService
> {
>     public class AdventureWorksService : EntityFrameworkDataService<AdventureWorks2014Entities>
>     {
>         // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
>         public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
>         {
>             // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
>             // Examples:
>             // config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntityset", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
>             // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
>             config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
>             config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("SalesOrderHeaders", EntitySetRights.All);
>             config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

However, now I'm stuck at 'Define the user interface of the window' of the walkthrough :(

Edit 1: Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14321821/5341492), I managed to complete the walkthrough.

Sryn