# Metadata error in Walkthrough: Binding WPF Controls to a WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Like in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818525/cant-discover-the-service-following-walkthrough-binding-wpf-controls-to-a-wcf/23941884#23941884)

I cant go on because of metadata. 
It still doesnt work for me. I changed the localhost number

```
address="http://localhost:54786/AdventureWorksService/mex"
```

the rest I left how it was but it did not work... tryed it in APP.CONFIG or WEB.CONFIG... I tryed even with adding `<system.serviceModel>...</system.serviceModel>`

I still get the metadata error. Please help me with detailed solution if possible.

Here is the *web.config*

```
 <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime tar

getFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorks2012Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AdventureWorksModel.csdl|res://*/AdventureWorksModel.ssdl|res://*/AdventureWorksModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\Projects;initial catalog=AdventureWorks2012;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date,Time,Extension,Size" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is the *app.config*

```
    <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
        </startup>

  <!--<system.serviceModel>-->
  <services>
    <service name="AdventureWorksService"
             behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport">
      <endpoint
          address="http://localhost:54786/AdventureWorksService/mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
          />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="metadataSupport">
        <serviceMetadata/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <!--</system.serviceModel>-->

</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post your .xml file. And also check if you have applied any security settings.

Comment: I posted the configs :)

Answer (score 1):

Some missing information in the question, but I'll give it a guess.

You do not expose metadata, which in turn prevents you from adding a service reference. Doublecheck that you have the `httpGetEnabled="true"` in the configuration (`web.config`) for application that hosts the service. If you are using `HTTPS`, then switch the element with `httpsGetEnabled="true"`. You can combine the two if needed.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

**EDIT**: You would get a clear message stating this if you try to open the given service url in your browser.

**EDIT2:**

You need to include a service behavior, and the service endpoint with a contract. The `name` attribute refers to the service implementation. The namespace for the service, including the service name but without the .svc file extension. The `contract` attribute refers to the contract interface which that is also created when you choose new wcf service.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service 
          name="MyApp.Services.MyService"
          behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
       <endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="MyApp.Services.IMyService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" /> <!-- Set this to true to return exception details to the calling client. -->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Try adding this configuration and edit the appropriate attributes, and then open the service in a web browser. The client should automatically get the `app.config` updated when you add the service through the `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Johnny: You are missing the definitions for the service in the `web.config`

Comment: I am a total noob at WCF and XAML... So please show me where I am missing exactly what!?

Comment: Could you do the walkthrough and see if you get to the same point? I takes 5 minutes to get to this pint. And than put in the full XML of the Web.config and also it which project you mean... becouse I cant figure out where to insert what

Comment: The last config snippet should be in web.config at your server (or project that has the wcf service). The client config will be updated accordingly when you add a service reference.